# H2 refuses to create auto_increment for Postgres emulated database

Tags: sql, postgresql, h2

I created an in memory H2 database with JDBC URL

```
jdbc:h2:~/test;MODE=PostgreSQL;DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE;DEFAULT_NULL_ORDERING=HIGH
```

The H2 web console refuses to let me do an auto_increment. I've seen serial for Postgres, but that doesn't work either.

At it's simplest, it hates:

```
create table test(id bigint auto_increment);
Syntax error in SQL statement "create table test(id bigint [*]auto_increment)"; expected "ARRAY, INVISIBLE, VISIBLE, NOT NULL, NULL, AS, DEFAULT, GENERATED, ON UPDATE, NOT NULL, NULL, DEFAULT ON NULL, NULL_TO_DEFAULT, SEQUENCE, SELECTIVITY, COMMENT, CONSTRAINT, COMMENT, PRIMARY KEY, UNIQUE, NOT NULL, NULL, CHECK, REFERENCES, ,, )"; SQL statement:
create table test(id bigint auto_increment) [42001-214] 42001/42001 (Help)
```

**Why do I care:**

My code base was failing with NULL not allowed for column "REV". I'm using JPA/Hibernate + Liquibase. In order to try the suggestions at

[Hibernate Envers + Liquibase: NULL not allowed for column "REV"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62060943/hibernate-envers-liquibase-null-not-allowed-for-column-rev)

I'm trying to add an auto_increment to my Liquibase changelog file.

Comment: `auto_increment` would be invalid for Postgres as well.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I found the official H2 source burried among many other apparently  bad guides in a search result. The consistent thing I saw was auto_increment. However, as you mentioned the H2 source says it's not supported. But ideally I want something that works with both real Postgres and emulated Postgres on H2. Can you recommend something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the SQL Standard's generation clause `GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY`. For example:

```
create table test (
  id bigint generated always as identity, 
  name varchar(10)
);
```

See [PostgreSQL Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=a4a34b31744c862b69f62eab2750e104).

It works the same way in H2. For example:

```
create table test(id bigint generated always as identity, name varchar(10));

insert into test (name) values ('Chicago') ;

select * from test;
```

Result:

```
ID  NAME   
--  -------
 1  Chicago
```